# Issue with www-data user and /home/user/www permissions

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, home-directory, apache2.4

I have an issue with the use of /home as www folder.
Actually I'm using userdir mod on ubuntu 14.04 and apache2.4 in order to have all my websites in home folder. Everything was working so far.
But I made a mistake in my permissions and my www-data user write in the folder of my home, and he becomes owner of the written files. Which makes the true home folder owner incapable to delete it.

I tried (with root access) :

```
chmod -R 775 /home/administrateur/
chmod -R ug+rwx  /home/administrateur/
chown -R administrateur:administrateur /home/administrateur/
chgrp -R administrateur /home/administrateur/
```

With no success, the files which are written remains the property of www-data.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Could you post `namei -mo /home/administrateur` and `ls -l /home/administrateur` commands output?

Comment: Ok @Letizia first of all, www-data is writing in a subfolder in `/home/administrateur/www/subfolder`
For the returns :
`namei -mo /home/administrateur` returns :
 `drwxr-xr-x root           root           /
 drwxr-xr-x root           root           home
 drwxrwxr-x administrateur administrateur administrateur`
`ls -l /home/administrateur` returns :
`drwxrwxr-x 6 administrateur administrateur        4096 Oct  9 14:55 www`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `sudo` before your commands, because if you don't  have  write access on your files, you can't change their attributes.

Comment: I edited my post. I used the root account.